# ray casting функция

Tags: c++, sfml, raytracing

я делаю 3д игру используя метод raytracing только после столкновения с объектом я не создаю ещё несколько лучей а сразу сохраняю полученный цвет.
я только начал проект всё что у меня есть:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace sf;
int WIDTH=800;
int HEIGHT=600;
int bits_per_pixel=32;
/*
* 
*/
Color cast_ray() {
return Color(0,0,0);
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
RenderWindow window(VideoMode(WIDTH,HEIGHT,32),"GAME");
while(window.isOpen()){
    Event event;
    while(window.pollEvent(event)){if(event.type==Event::Closed){window.close();}}
    window.clear(Color(100,200,255,0));
    RectangleShape floor(Vector2f(WIDTH,HEIGHT/2));
    floor.setPosition(0,HEIGHT/2);
    floor.setFillColor(Color(150,100,100));
    window.draw(floor);
    window.display();
}
return 0;
}
```

я только начал изучать С++. Мне нужна помощь с созданием функции cast ray возвращающей цвет. я использую sfml для создания окна

Answer (score 0):

Обсуждение на тему освещения в SFML с использованием OpenGL: https://www.cyberforum.ru/sfml/thread2687849.html#post14783019